# How to set TTL value for a table in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-tables

Does Azure Cosmos DB support setting a `TTL` for a Table? How can we set that from code while creating the table with `CreateIfNotExists` call? (I am using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`) I am not looking for setting it per-item basis (I found in feature requests that it is not available as a feature yet) and want it to be applicable on all entries in the table.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550860/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-change-ttl-on-a-cosmos-db-table) answer your question?