# The connection string is missing a required property: AccountEndpoint error while using the new CosmosClient(CosmosConnectionString)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I am getting `The connection string is missing a required property: AccountEndpoint` error while using the `new CosmosClient(CosmosConnectionString)` constructor for `CosmosClient` with assembly `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client, Version=3.11.0.0` - How to fix it? The connection string from the account looks like (AccountEndpoint is missing:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devdb;AccountKey=xxxx;TableEndpoint=https://devdb.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/;
```

Answer (score 2):

The connection string you're specifying is for connecting to an Azure Storage account (when you use `Azure.Storage.*` Nuget package) or a Cosmos DB account targeting Table API (when you use (`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` package).

To connect to a Cosmos DB account using `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` package, connection string must be specified in `AccountEndpoint=https://account-name.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=account-key;` format.

Comment: When I copy the connection string from the db I created, I get `TableEndpoint` in that but that, now, needs to be converted to `AccountEndpoint`. What is the standard why to do that?
The table endpoint looks like: TableEndpoint=https://account-name.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/
While the other one looks like: AccountEndpoint=https://account-name.documents.azure.com:443/
What is the standard way to get the second given we have first one stored in our secret? (For all clouds) Is string replace reliabe to convert `table.cosmos` part to `documents`?