# CosmosDB per item ttl setting throwing exception: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, json-deserialization, json-serialization, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I am following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-time-to-live?tabs=dotnetv2%2Cjavav4#dotnet-set-ttl-item) to set per item `ttl` to a CosmosDB table entries. But when I add a field name `ttl` in the entity class I am facing the below error while making Insert/Replace calls:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'ttl.$t', line 1, position 109.

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ttl", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? ttl { get; set; }

    public MyEntity(
       string pk,
       string rk,
       string prop)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = pk;
        this.RowKey = rk;
        this.Prop =prop;
        this.ttl = -1;
    }
}
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Follow the offical document and update my Items in `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator`. Items will be deleted according to the expected value of `TTL`.

```
while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    foreach (var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
    {
       item.ttl = 10;
       await container.UpsertItemAsync<MyEntity>(item, new PartitionKey(item.address));
    }
}
```

[image]

***Hope my answer can help you.***

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;

namespace CosmosGettingStartedTutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        // <Main>
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning operations...\n");
                CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://localhost:8081/", "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");
                Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("ToDoList");
                Container container = database.GetContainer("jason");
                // Add for an item
                QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("select * from c ");
                FeedIterator<MyEntity> feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyEntity>(queryDefinition, null, new QueryRequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("address0") });
                int count = 0;
                while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                    {
                        if (item.id == "0")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("id equal 0  is exist: id = " + item.id);
                            Console.WriteLine("We will change id='test" + item.id + "'");
                            Console.WriteLine("pls wait ，will update ");
                            item.id = "test" + item.id;
                            await container.UpsertItemAsync<MyEntity>(item, new PartitionKey(item.address));
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                int num = count + 5;
                for (int i = count; i < num; i++)
                {
                    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString());
                    entity.id = i.ToString();
                    entity.address = "address0";
                    await container.CreateItemAsync<MyEntity>(entity, new PartitionKey(entity.address));
                }
            }
            catch (CosmosException de)
            {
                Exception baseException = de.GetBaseException();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} error occurred: {1}", de.StatusCode, de);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of demo, press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        public class MyEntity : TableEntity
        {
            public string Prop { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ttl", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public int? ttl { get; set; }

            public MyEntity(string pk, string rk, string prop)
            {
                this.PartitionKey = pk;
                this.RowKey = rk;
                this.Prop = prop;
                this.ttl = -1;
            }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you confirm that the TTL did help deleting the entry? I observed the row level TTL does not actually delete my table entry.

Comment: @SayantanGhosh I manually updated the value of ttl in `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` and found that it is possible to delete entries.

Comment: @SayantanGhoshs  I also update items by code, it work for me. ^-^

Comment: Thanks, I will debug why in my case the entry does not get deleted in a min when I set ttl to 60/30 etc values with Default ttl = -1 for the table. Also I hit the mentioned exception when I use Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table ExecuteBatch call with a TableBatchOperation for Insert.

Comment: @SayantanGhosh My code debugging here is `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator`, and the results are all normal. If you are using Azure Cosmos DB in Azure and you still have problems, I suggest you can raise a support ticket in portal.

Comment: @SayantanGhosh Regarding this issue, there should be no problem in terms of code. Hope it helps you.